# Null pointer exception for button value

Tags: android, web-services

I got a problem with my web services. My layout contains these fields

```
username  edittextbox

password  edittextbox

gender   button(male), button(female)

mailid   edittextbox
```

Whenever I click the  male button for gender option it should take the string value as male and for female it should take female.  I couldn't able to write the exact code as I am new to android becoz of which I'm getting null pointer exception in the logcat.

I want to add these string values to request obj of my webservices to send the data to server like   request.addProperty("gender", gender); according to user selection

some one please help me to write the exact code for gender option so that i will not get any NPE in logcat

the code is

```
Button regmalebtn;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
public void register() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");

    EditText etxt_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetfirstname);
    EditText etxt_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetlastname);
    EditText etxt_dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetdob);
    EditText etxt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetemail);
    EditText etxt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetpwd);
    EditText etxt_mobno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetmobno);
    EditText deviceid = null;
    String fname = etxt_user.getText().toString();
    String lname = etxt_pass.getText().toString();
    String dob = etxt_dob.getText().toString();
    String email = etxt_email.getText().toString();
    String password = etxt_password.getText().toString();
    String mobno = etxt_mobno.getText().toString();
    String gender= regmalebtn.getText().toString();
    int latitude =**;
    int longitude= **;
    String  device_id= "12345";
    // regmalebtn.sette

//  DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
    //      "http://.....");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);



    //String response1 = request.getProperty(0).toString() ;
    request.addProperty("fname", fname);
    request.addProperty("lname", lname);
    request.addProperty("dateofbirth", dob);
    request.addProperty("email", email);
    request.addProperty("password", password);
    request.addProperty("mobno", mobno);
    request.addProperty("latitude", latitude);
    request.addProperty("longitude", longitude);
    request.addProperty("device_id", device_id);
    request.addProperty("gender", gender);
    //request.addProperty("latitude',latitude);





    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

        SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope
                .getResponse();
        //SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        String resultData;
        resultData = request.getProperty(0).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

These are the logcat errors

```
06-16 11:55:58.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(471): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
06-16 11:55:58.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(471): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 11:55:58.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(471):     at com.soap.Register.register(Register.java:125)
06-16 11:55:58.955: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(471):     at com.soap.Register$1$1.run(Register.java:66)
06-16 11:55:58.965: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.soap/.Register
```

Comment: It looks like you have NPE in internal `Runnable` class that is located in your `com.soap.Register` class.

Comment: post your code where your initializing button and fetching string from textView

Comment: @inazaruk hi, actually im calling the register method inside the button click like this                 signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(0);
    t = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
      register();
     }
    };
    t.start();
   }
  });
 }

Comment: @devA hi dev , i m not getting the exact Idea to write the code for the buttons and  I tried to solve it myself but I couldnt able to do that, But I know the code which I have written for the buttons is wrong. any Idea to solve? see the code once which i posted now

Comment: seems like there is problem with your register method... if its some local method can u post it...

Comment: @devA hi, actually im calling the register method inside the button click like this signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { showDialog(0); t = new Thread() { public void run() { register(); } }; t.start(); } }); } and below this i have written the code for register method which I have posted

Comment: @devA if i add the exact code for the buttons(male/female) the problem will be solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a:

```
Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regetmalebtn);
```

Or something like that.

I cannot see where you're specifying your regmalebtn elsewhere, so this

```
String gender= regmalebtn.getText().toString();
```

Would cause a null pointer since you've only got this

```
Button regmalebtn;
```

atm

Comment: thanks a lot for ur response, now no error i m getting but how can we show the message on the emulator whether we r registered successfully or not.which functionality should we use for printing a message or dialog box

Comment: I cleared the exceptions but in the logcat I am getting this message  06-16 15:43:41.565: VERBOSE/HELLO(885): Trying to Login
06-16 15:43:43.265: VERBOSE/TAG(885): -1  why I m getting -1

Comment: Don't know about that error you get in Logcat. You should check out toasts ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)) for printing some easy info.